# Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL - Warning arises with poltergeist, but not selenium-webdriver

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, selenium, poltergeist

I have been running Cucumber tests on my Rails app for some time using Selenium-Webdriver as a javascript driver and had stable results.  I tried switching to Poltergeist in order to run headless.

A couple of my tests run a test Stripe transaction, which triggers a javascript popup.  I have steps like:

```
When(/^I wait to see "([^"]*)" in a Stripe popup$/) do |arg1|
  within_frame 'stripe_checkout_app' do
    wait_until do
      expect(page).to have_content(arg1)
    end
  end
end
```

These kinds of steps ran perfectly fine when I used selenium as my Capybara javascript driver, but they fail when I use `:poltergeist` as the javascript driver.  I get errors like:

```
 Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://127.0.0.1:64780/charges/1/edit from frame with URL https://checkout.stripe.com/v3/VguVZoYKogJUsO05PpIlfA.html?distinct_id=ad0ab5bb-c346-dac7-62dc-2a4a8e4dcf64. Domains, protocols and ports must match.
```

Does anyone know why this kind of error would arise with `poltergeist`, but not with `selenium-webdriver`?

Comment: What version of FF and selenium-webdriver were you using, and what version of phantomjs are you using now?

Answer (score 0):

You can probably get rid of that message by disabling web security - phantomjs_options = ['--web-security=false'] - in your poltergeist driver registration.  However, are you sure it's an error and not just a warning?  Any modern browser will prevent access between frames from different domains (and should for very real security reasons).